# Error: 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php

[image]

I have a PHP code that is adding millions of rows in MySQL table. It will take 1 month for it to complete, if the script runs continuously. So i just want to remove the whole limit thing or increase it to max.

But I can split it the proccess in parts (like run the file code for 1 hour, then reload the page, then run it again). So at least can i increase the limit to 1 hour?

Comment: Run the script from [CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php).

Comment: You mean CRON job @BenM?

Comment: No, check the link above. CLI = command line interface.

Comment: I have no idea about it, and i need to learn it just for this thing. And i am not good at learning things fast, it iwll take me months, maybe. Can't i just simply increase the time limit? just by changing some value, somewhere, if you tell me sir?